# Extract specific string using RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string something like this,

```
Example 1 @abc@xy<a href="http://-example.com">-example.com</a> and @xyz@abc.com Example 2
```

Now, I want to remove the string occurring after the second `@` encountered, i.e. `@example.com` `@abc.com` and preserve the rest of the data which should look like,

> Example 1 @abc and @xyz Example 2

I have tried a lot of RegExp and saw many examples but have had no luck so far.

If anyone has tried something similar, it'd be great if you can help me out.

Comment: _the string occurring after the second @_ - do you have a clear definition of what belongs to that string and what not? In your example it seems to be `@xy<a href="http://-example.com">-example.com</a>` - why not `@xy` or `@xy<a href="http://-example.com">-example.com</a> and`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/11683

Comment: Hey, `@xy<a href="http://-example.com">-example.com</a>` This whole part needs to be replaced. `and` is to be preserved.

Comment: Will `and` be always in the end of second `@`?

Comment: @ShreyaShah I figgured as much, but it isn't clear to me, why you want exactly that part. What rules do you have to determine, that `@xy<a href="http://-example.com">-example.com</a>` is what you want - is it _any non space characters and the complete tag that follows if there is one_? Defining this for us should also help yourself build the regex, as clear cut borders is what one needs to build a well working regex.

Comment: @SebastianProske `and` is just another string, it could be anything. Alright we can just focus on `@xyz@abc.com Example 2` and remove the part followed by the second `@` and preserve Example 2.

Comment: @ShreyaShah that would be `(@[^\s@]*)@[^\s@]*` and replace with `$1`. What's the language you use to implement this?

Comment: @SebastianProske Javascript

Comment: hey @SebastianProske thanks a ton, man! Works like a charm. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second half of your sample you can simply match both `@`s and replace only the second on, by grouping and using them in the replace.

Pattern: `/(@[^\s@]*)@[^\s@]*/g`
Replacement: `'$1'`

This matches an @ followed by anything but spaces and @ and stores it in group 1. It then matches the next @ and again anythihng but spaces and @.

If there might be other stuff between both @s, you could adjust your pattern to use `(@[^@]*)` for the capturing group.

Four the first part of your sample, you would have to find a better pattern to match what follows the second @, this could be something along `@[^\s@<]*(?:<[^<>]*>[^<>]*<\/[^<>]*>)` but I'm not quite sure about your requirements and matching along tags is always tricky.

Comment: Works.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern: `^[^@]*@[^@]+(?=@)`. It will match everything before second `@`. It anchors at the beginning of a string, first it matches everything except `@`: `[^@]`, then matches `@`, then again matches everything except `@`: `[^@]`, until next `@` is met: `(?=@)` (positive lookahead).

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OCNHdo/3)

Comment: hey thanks, but it only works if my string starts with an `@` which is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Capture the first `@` followed by non-`@` characters in a group, then match `@` again followed by non-space characters, and replace with the first captured group:

```
(@[^@]+?)@[^ ]+?(?= )
```

Result:

```
Example 1 @abc and @xyz Example 2
```

https://regex101.com/r/mXRlsZ/1

Note that this will also replace any `@`s in a row, past the first - eg `@abc@xy@foo` will become `@abc`

Comment: You don't need all those non-greedy quantifiers and the positive lookahead: `(@[^@]+)@\S+`

Answer (score 0):

```
string input = @"Example 1 @abc@xy<a href=""http://-example.com"">-example.com</a> and @xyz@abc.com Example 2";
string pattern = @"@.+?(?=@|$)";
int x = 0;
string s = Regex.Replace(
    input,
    pattern,
    m => ++x == 2 ? Regex.Match(m.Value, @">(\s+.+?\s+)$").Groups[1].Value : m.Value);
```

#### Explanation

First, start with searching for `@` symbol. Variable `x` is tracking the number of occurrences of `@`. As soon as it hits 2, then we extract everything between the end and `>`. If `x` doesn't equal to 2, then we just return the match (`m.Value`);